# Returning html code in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to print html code in Javascript code.
I want to open and close the bottom line of five li tags. How can I do this with a for loop

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   InsertLi();
});

function InsertLi(){
   var count = 5;
   for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       var codeBlock = ' <li>' + i + '</li>';
       $(".bildirimMetin").html(codeBlock);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bildirimMetin">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, another solution, close to your code, with `html`, store all strings in your variable via `+=` then you must define your variable before `for` loop also move your `html` after it. Your current code not working because it just store last string not all.

```js
InsertLi();

function InsertLi() {
  var count = 5;
  var codeBlock = '';
  
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    codeBlock += '<li>' + i + '</li>';
  }
  
  $(".bildirimMetin").html(codeBlock);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bildirimMetin">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `append` function instead. `html` function every time overrides your html content with the new content and you get only the last one. Also create your string with 5 `li`-s and then call the `append` at the end to work with `DOM` one time and have more performance.

```js
function InsertLi() {
   var count = 5;
   var codeBlock = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       codeBlock += ' <li>' + i + '</li>';
   }
   
   $(".bildirimMetin").append(codeBlock);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   InsertLi();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bildirimMetin"></ul>
```

If you have only one item with `bildirimMetin` class, it will be better to use `id` instead of `class`.

Answer (score 1):

you had a couple issues.  One was overwriting the inner HTML instead of appending.  The other was a syntax issue.

```
function InsertLi(){
 var count = 5;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var codeBlock = ' <li>' + i + '</li>';
        $(".bildirimMetin").append(codeBlock);
   }
 }

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
InsertLi();
}
);
```